# It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs on Windows Docker Desktop

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, https, dockerfile

Why do I get this message when I run the docker image in the Windows Docker Desktop?

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I start to build the image with: docker build -t idp -f Dockerfile.IDP .

Next I start the image with this command: docker run --name idp -it -dt -p 8443:443 idp

This is how my Dockerfile look like:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build

    # copy this first so the restore layer gets cached when the csproj files are unchanged
    COPY ./*.sln ./
    COPY ./src/ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj ./src/ProjectA/
    WORKDIR /src
    RUN dotnet restore ./ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj
    COPY . /
    RUN dotnet build ./ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj -c release --no-restore

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish ./ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj -c release --no-build -o /app/publish
    COPY ./*.pfx /app/publish

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS runtime
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish ./

    RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
    ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
    ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:443"
    ENV TZ=Europe/Amsterdam

    VOLUME /app

    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectA.dll"]
    EXPOSE 443
```

What am I missing here?

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

The mean idear is to run the .NET Core 3.1 application on a linux container with HTTPS.

I already looked for an accepted answer that could help me, but I didn't find any so far.

I got it to work with the folling somehow:

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:latest

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest

and the build and run with the commands given above.

It magically worked. But I'm not amused that it sometimes works and sometimes not. After I start it, I removed the mcr.* pulls and restart the app again and it still works.
Any idears why and how to solve it to a perminant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [new set](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2375) of [sdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/) and [aspnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/) images, in your case:

- `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-alpine`
- `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-alpine`

Comment: But why do I need them to pull separatly? They already defined in the Dockerfile. Because when the app is running and I delete these pulled images, the app is working after that. My thought is that I'm missing something in the dockerfile.

Comment: Can you try changing the images in your Dockerfile with the ones I provided and see if that behavior persists?

Comment: Hi, sorry no success. I tried to run this in the container: `dotnet dev-certs https`
But it comes with the same message.

Comment: `dotnet dev-certs` is not supposed to work within a runtime image. You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide) more about how can you make ir work.